# Join pub/sub real time data with BQ side input slowly changing data

Tags: python, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working on a use case where I need to join real time events (read from pub/sub) that are processed using a sliding window with a slowly changing data (read from BQ).

This is the code to read BQ slowly changing data

```
side_pcol = (p | PeriodicImpulse(fire_interval=60*30, apply_windowing=True)
                 | "To BQ Request" >> beam.ParDo(to_bqrequest, sql=sql)
                 | beam.io.ReadAllFromBigQuery()
                 | "product -> category lookup" >> beam.Map(product_category_lookup)
                 )
```

And this is the part to process data in a sliding window from pub/sub

```
input_data = (
        p
        | "Read from Pub/Sub"
        >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.input_topic)
        | "Decode JSON" >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
        | "Filter Events without product_id"
        >> beam.Filter(lambda data: data.get("event_type") == "product_view")
    )
    # Apply windowing to the data
    windowed_data = input_data | "Apply Windowing" >> beam.WindowInto(
        beam.window.SlidingWindows(
            size=60, period=30
        )  # sliding window of 15 minutes, triggers every 10 min
    )
```

This is the part where I merge the 2 data

```
filtered_data = (windowed_data | "Merge" >> beam.Map(merge, side=beam.pvalue.AsList(side_pcol)))
```

This pipeline runs using Datfalow runner however the graph is bit strange. The stage
`ReadAllFromBigQuery` is duplicated 3 times and `product -> category lookup` is duplicated 2 times. Please see the graphe below. Any hints why is this happening?[image]

Comment: Hi @Khalil, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.